# isEqualToString always returns true

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

```
for (Annotation *ann in annotaionArray) // annotationArray contains annotations added to map
{
    NSString *fetchedtitle = ann.title;

    if([fetchedtitle isEqualToString:oldTitle]); // oldTitle = textfield.text
    {
        ann.title = appDelegate.pinTitle;
        break;
    }
}
```

But the comparison is always true. What could be the error please?

fetched const char from sqlite is casted to `stringWithUTF8String`.

Everything has been done to cast perfectly to string but still why is the error in comparison?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the trailing semi-colon!

```
if ([fetchedtitle isEqualToString:oldTitle])
{
    ann.title = appDelegate.pinTitle;
    break;
}
```

**With** the semi-colon, your code is the same as:

```
if ([fetchedtitle isEqualToString:oldTitle])
    ;
{
    ann.title = appDelegate.pinTitle;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a semi colon at the end of your IF statement your code is :

```
if( [fetchedtitle isEqualToString:oldTitle])
            {
            // Do nothing
            }

// this will always run
  ann.title = appDelegate.pinTitle;
                break;
```

Answer (score 1):

replace the following line

```
if([fetchedtitle isEqualToString:oldTitle]);
```

with

```
if([fetchedtitle isEqualToString:oldTitle])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove semicolon(;) from the following part of your code...

```
if([fetchedtitle isEqualToString:oldTitle]);
```